# Filter #tag tweets for a specific account using Twitter Streaming API

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter-hbc

I am able to get tweets from a specific account using the streaming API. I can also manage to get tweets for specific #tags like below:

```
endpoint.trackTerms(Lists.newArrayList("twitterapi", "@myTwitter"));
```

and

```
endpoint.trackTerms(Lists.newArrayList("twitterapi", "#yolo"));
```

I wonder how to merge these two queries as I want to get specific tweets (#yolo) from a specific user (@myTwitter)

Code can be found here
https://github.com/twitter/hbc

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to Twitter's documentation on the streaming API, how to [track terms](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview/request-parameters#track):

> A comma-separated list of phrases which will be used to determine what
>   Tweets will be delivered on the stream. A phrase may be one or more
>   terms separated by spaces, and a phrase will match if all of the terms
>   in the phrase are present in the Tweet, regardless of order and
>   ignoring case. By this model, you can think of commas as logical ORs,
>   while spaces are equivalent to logical ANDs (e.g. ‘the twitter’ is the
>   AND twitter, and ‘the,twitter’ is the OR twitter).

`twitter-hbc` only allows to track terms separated by commas, so if you do this,

```
endpoint.trackTerms(Lists.newArrayList("@myTwitter", "#yolo"));
```

You will actually be doing `@myTwitter OR #yolo`, take a look to the implementation of the method `trackTerms`,

```
/**
  * @param terms a list of Strings to track. These strings should NOT be url-encoded.
  */
public StatusesFilterEndpoint trackTerms(List<String> terms) {
    addPostParameter(Constants.TRACK_PARAM, Joiner.on(',').join(terms));
    return this;
}
```

Instead of using `trackTerms`, you could add the terms directly to the endpoint like this,

```
endpoint.addPostParameter(Constants.TRACK_PARAM, Joiner.on(' ').join(Lists.newArrayList("twitterapi", "#yolo")));
```

Or of course you could create a new method.

Hope it helps.